# Не работает ArrayList фильтр Android

Tags: android

есть проблемы с фильтром ArrayList'а.

Сам фильтр находиться в адаптере, не знаю правильно ли это или нет.

Вот сам код:

**PostAdapter**

```
public class PostAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

    private final static int FADE_DURATION = 0;
    private static final int TYPE_HEADER = 0;
    private static final int TYPE_ITEM = 1;
    private static final int TYPE_FOOTER = 2;
    private String TAG="LoadImage";

    private Context context;

    Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
    public ArrayList<Posts> questionList = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<Posts> arraylist = new ArrayList<>();

    private boolean mWithHeader;
    private boolean mWithFooter;
    private View.OnClickListener mOnClickListener;

    PostAdapter(ArrayList<Posts> posts, Context context, boolean withHeader, boolean withFooter) {
        this.context=context;
        this.mWithHeader=withHeader;
        this.mWithFooter=withFooter;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {

        if (mWithHeader && isPositionHeader(position))
            return TYPE_HEADER;
        if (mWithFooter && isPositionFooter(position))
            return TYPE_FOOTER;
        return TYPE_ITEM;
    }
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {

        if(viewType==TYPE_HEADER) {

            return new header(LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.header, viewGroup, false));
        }
        else if(viewType==TYPE_FOOTER){
            return new footer(LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.footer, viewGroup, false));
        }
        else {
            CardStylePreferencesManager cardStylePreferencesManager = new CardStylePreferencesManager(context);
            int CardLayout;
            if(cardStylePreferencesManager.loadCardStyle() == true) {
                CardLayout = R.layout.postitemmini;
            } else {
                CardLayout = R.layout.postitem;
            }
            View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(CardLayout, viewGroup, false);
            VideoViewHolder holder = new VideoViewHolder(itemView);
            itemView.setTag(holder);

            return holder;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        if(holder instanceof  header){
            //((header) holder).vName.setText(album_name);
        }
        else if(holder instanceof  footer){
            ((footer) holder).context = context;
        }
        else {
            Posts post=getItem(position);
            ((VideoViewHolder)holder).vTitle.setText(Html.fromHtml(post.getTitle()));
            String postExcerpt = post.getExcerpt();
            ((VideoViewHolder)holder).vExcerpt.setText(Html.fromHtml(postExcerpt.substring(3, postExcerpt.length() - 1)));
            ((VideoViewHolder) holder).context = context;
            ((VideoViewHolder) holder).content=post.getContent();
            ((VideoViewHolder) holder).attachment=post.getPostAttahment();
            ((VideoViewHolder) holder).posturl=post.getPostURL();
            ((VideoViewHolder) holder).title=post.getTitle();
            GlideApp.with(context)
                    .load(post.getPostImg())
                    .thumbnail(0.2f)
                    .apply(fitCenterTransform())
                    .fitCenter()
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.RESOURCE)
                    .skipMemoryCache(false)
                     .listener(new RequestListener<Drawable>() {
                         @Override
                         public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {

                             Log.e(TAG, "Load failed", e);

                             for (Throwable t : e.getRootCauses()) {
                                 Log.e(TAG, "Caused by", t);
                             }
                             e.logRootCauses(TAG);
                             return false;
                         }

                         @Override
                         public boolean onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                             return false;
                         }
                     })
                    .into(((VideoViewHolder) holder).vImage);

        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        int itemCount=0;
       if(questionList!=null) {


    itemCount = questionList.size();
    if (mWithHeader)
        itemCount = itemCount + 1;
    if (mWithFooter)
        itemCount = itemCount + 1;
   }
return itemCount;
    }


    private boolean isPositionHeader(int position) {
        return position == 0;
    }

    private boolean isPositionFooter(int position) {
        return position == getItemCount() - 1;
    }
    public void setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener lis) {
        mOnClickListener = lis;
    }

    protected Posts getItem(int position) {
        return mWithHeader ? questionList.get(position - 1) : questionList.get(position);
    }

    private int getItemPosition(int position){
        return mWithHeader ? position - 1 : position;
    }

    public void setData(ArrayList<Posts> questionList) {
        this.questionList=questionList;
    }

    public class VideoViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        protected ImageView vImage;
        protected ImageView vReadImage;
        protected TextView vName;
        protected CardView vCard;
        protected TextView vDetails,vTitle,vExcerpt;
        String content;
        String posturl;
        String title;
        String attachment;

        protected  Context context;

        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.P)
        public VideoViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            vImage = (ImageView)  v.findViewById(R.id.blog_image);
            vReadImage = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.img_read);
            vReadImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_visibility_off);
            vTitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title);
            vExcerpt=(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.excerpt);
            vCard = (CardView) v.findViewById(R.id.vcard);
            vImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Posts posts = new Posts();
                    vReadImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_visibility);
                    Intent fullScreenIntent=new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), PostFullScreen.class);
                    fullScreenIntent.putExtra("content",content);
                    fullScreenIntent.putExtra("attachment",attachment);
                    fullScreenIntent.putExtra("posturl",posturl);
                    fullScreenIntent.putExtra("title",title);
                    context.startActivity(fullScreenIntent);
                }
            });
            vCard.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Posts posts = new Posts();
                    vReadImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_visibility);
                    Intent fullScreenIntent=new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), PostFullScreen.class);
                    fullScreenIntent.putExtra("content",content);
                    fullScreenIntent.putExtra("attachment",attachment);
                    fullScreenIntent.putExtra("posturl",posturl);
                    fullScreenIntent.putExtra("title",title);
                    context.startActivity(fullScreenIntent);
                }
            });
            vReadImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Posts posts = new Posts();
                        vReadImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_visibility_off);
                }
            });
        }

        public void clearAnimation() {
            this.clearAnimation();
        }


    }

    public class header extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {


        protected Context context;
        protected int position;

        public header(View v) {
            super(v);


        }


    }
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
                String charString = charSequence.toString();
                if (charString.isEmpty()) {
                    arraylist = questionList;
                } else {
                    ArrayList<Posts> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (Posts posts : questionList) {

                        // здесь мы отбираем нужные данные
                        if (posts.getTitle().toLowerCase().contains(charString.toLowerCase()) || posts.getExcerpt().contains(charSequence)) {
                            filteredList.add(posts);
                        }
                    }

                    arraylist = filteredList;
                }

                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                filterResults.values = arraylist;
                return filterResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
                arraylist = (ArrayList<Posts>) filterResults.values;

                // обновляем список отфильтрованных данных
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
    }


    public class footer extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {


        protected  Context context;
        protected int position;

        public footer(View v) {
            super(v);


        }


    }
}
```

Также использую класс Fragment

```
public class ListFragment extends BackHandledFragment  {
    public static String TAG="postFrag";
    public ArrayList<Posts> mPosts;
    public PostAdapter postAdapter;
    public File file;

    private PostModel postModel;
    private  Observer<ArrayList<Posts>> postsObserver;
    private OLEDPreferencesManager sharedpref;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false);
    }
    @SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        final RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.recyclerHome);
        Posts posts = new Posts();
        postAdapter=new PostAdapter(mPosts,getContext(),false,false);
        postAdapter.getFilter().filter("Какое-то слово для фильтрации");
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        mPosts = new ArrayList<Posts>();
        recyclerView.setAdapter(postAdapter);
        final ConstraintLayout bottomconstraint = (ConstraintLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.bottom_constraint);
        final FloatingActionButton TopFab = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.TopFab);
        final Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        final BottomNavigationView BottomNav = (BottomNavigationView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.bottom_nav);
        final CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams bottomParams = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) bottomconstraint.getLayoutParams();
        TopFab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(0);
                if (toolbar.getParent() instanceof AppBarLayout){
                    ((AppBarLayout)toolbar.getParent()).setExpanded(true,true);
                }
                bottomconstraint.requestLayout();


            }
        });
        AppBarLayout appBarLayout = (AppBarLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
        appBarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener(new AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int i) {
                if(i == 0) {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
                        toolbar.setElevation(0);
                    }
                    TopFab.hide();
                } else {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
                        toolbar.setElevation(8);
                    }
                    TopFab.show();
                }
            }
        });
        postModel= ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(PostModel.class);
            postModel.getPostsList().observe(this, new Observer<List<Posts>>() {
                @Override
                public void onChanged(@Nullable List<Posts> posts) {
                    postAdapter.setData((ArrayList<Posts>) posts);
                    postAdapter.notifyItemChanged(postModel.getChangeIndex());
                    Log.d(TAG,"On Changed method called");
                }
            });


    }
    public ListFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public String getTagText() {
        return TAG;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onBackPressed() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void RefreshLayout() {

    }



}
```

В ListFragment для фильтрации использую `postAdapter.getFilter().filter("Какое-то слово для фильтрации")`

Подскажите пожалуйста, что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для работы с фильтрами нужно использовать две коллекции данных. Первая это оригинальные данные, а вторая - отфильтрованные. В методах 'getItem'
'getItemCount''onBindViewHolder' - нужно ссылаться на вторую коллекцию.